# How to use winecfg headless?

Tags: linux, wine, winetricks

I cannot find documentation for how winetricks or winecfg create permanent exe overrides. I also would like to set desktop integration and windows version from the shell.

The reason for this is that I am testing a difficult program. It installs correctly sometimes, but not others. Tracking down the exact problem has led me to re-create a wine-prefix for it upwards of 10 times a day. It is simply not practical to use the GUI for that. I need to know the commands/options I can pass to winecfg/wine/winetricks so that I can create the initial prefix faster.

Is there any documentation for: **set permanent exe override** or **set desktop integration paths** or **set windows version** ? I appreciate any help with any of those three things!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like Windows does, everything in Wine is configured through the registry. Every single settings winecfg access can also be accessed through the registry using the `regedit` utility, which can also be used in command line to either import a big .reg file or set individual keys on the command line itself.

All the used keys are in the [Useful Registry Keys](http://wiki.winehq.org/UsefulRegistryKeys?highlight=%28registry%29) wiki page.

The easiest option in your case would be to export the configuration in a .reg file (right click on the keys you need, export) and then import then with `wine regedit MyConfig.reg` in your auto-configure script. You can write the .reg manually as well if you want, it's just a .ini-style text file.

Edit: wanted to add that as a comment as it doesn't answer the question itself but suggest another way of doing it but I lack reputation here: I'd recommend to just create a full copy of your clean pre-installation prefix and just copy it back when you need to reset. You will avoid the whole script to reconfigure a clean prefix, and will also be much faster than reinstalling libraries through winetricks and running regedit as all its a disk only operation.

Comment: I have been using the tar method, lol. In the future I will probably cobble together and ad-hoc bash script to write regfiles. God, the world we live in. Thanks for saving me fruitless searches, though!

Answer (score 0):

To change [Windows version](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winecfg#Windows_Version) using Winetricks, you can run:

```
winetricks -q win10
```

Available options are: nt351, nt40, vista, win10, win11, win20, win2k, win30, win31, win7, win8, win81, win95, win98, winme (basedon Wintricks source code).